# Loop through data set showing undefined

Tags: angular

I have the following data set that I am trying to display. It is a list of error messages. This is the structure I receive from an endpoint.

```
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  },
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": "Bad Request",
  "url": "https://localhost:5001/api/Corporates/Update/d0c71e53-bcbf-431f-84ef-6b65ac30202b",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/Corporates/Update/d0c71e53-bcbf-431f-84ef-6b65ac30202b: 400 Bad Request",
  "error": {
    "errors": {
      "Basics.Name": [
        "'Basics. Name' must not be empty."
      ],
      "Basics.PayrollDay": [
        "'Basics. Payroll Day' must be between 1 and 31 (exclusive). You entered 1."
      ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|ab03ae99-4476ede23f1c7cdb."
  }
}
```

Now I try and loop through it but get an undefined

```
for(let i = 0; i < error.error.errors.length; i++) {
 console.log(error.error.errors[i]);
}
```

The full code

```
this._corpService.updateCorporate(this.model).subscribe((corp) => {
  if (corp) {
     this._loader.stop();
     this._notificationService.openNotification('Corporate successfully updated.');
      }
    }, (error) => {
     this._loader.stop();
     for(let i = 0; i < error.error.errors.length; i++) {
     console.log(error.error.errors[i]);
  }
});
```

Any ideas why it's happening please

Comment: Show the complete `error` object

Comment: where is error variable?

Comment: I've added the full code for the relevant section

Comment: @skydev `Console.log(error)` and add it in the above code

Comment: error.error.errors.length = what is structure , that look wrong structure

Comment: @PranayRana I've updated just the "error" structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errors` is an object, not an array:

```
Object.entries(error.error.errors).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value))
```

or if you really want that for loop:

```
for (key in error.error.errors) {
  console.log(error.error.errors[key]);
}
```